# CSV with double quotes and separated by comma and space

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv file with all values in double quotes, all values separated by a comma and space, and column headers are in the first row:

```
"Exam date", "Last name", "First name", "DOB", "MRN"
"01/15/2019", "JOHN", "DOE", "01/15/2000", "0000000000"
"01/15/2020", "JANE", "ROE", "01/15/2010", "1111111111"
"01/15/2021", "BABY", "DOE", "01/15/2020", "2222222222"
```

I first tried `pd.read_csv('file.csv')`, but it only reads the first column:

|  | Exam date | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/15/2019 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 01/15/2019 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 01/15/2019 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I then tried `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',\s', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, engine='python')`, but it doesn't separate the columns:

|  | Exam date,"Last name","First name","DOB","MRN" |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | "01/15/2019","JOHN","DOE","01/15/2000"... |
| 1 | "01/15/2020","JANE","ROE","01/15/2010"... |
| 2 | "01/15/2021","BABY","DOE","01/15/2020",... |

How can I import this file properly?

---

**Update**: I realized the values are separated by a comma and null character, so I could import the file using `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',\0', engine='python')`:

|  | Exam date | "Last name" | "First name" | "DOB" | "MRN" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "01/15/2019" | "JOHN" | "DOE" | "01/15/2000" | "0000000000" |
| 1 | "01/15/2020" | "JANE" | "ROE" | "01/15/2010" | "1111111111" |
| 2 | "01/15/2021" | "BABY" | "DOE" | "01/15/2020" | "2222222222" |

However, all values (except the first column header) are impoted with double quotes. I tried `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',\0', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, engine='python')`, but the result was the same. How can I get rid of these double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created `file.csv` with `',\0'` as the separator as indicated in your update and reproduced your results:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(df)
```

```
    Exam date  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
0  01/15/2019         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1  01/15/2020         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2  01/15/2021         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I was able to pre-process the file using a file-like filter and get the correct values:

```py
import pandas as pd

class Filter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = open(filename, 'r', newline='')
    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.file.read(*args, **kwargs).replace('\0','')

df = pd.read_csv(Filter('file.csv'))
print(df)
```

```
    Exam date Last name First name         DOB         MRN
0  01/15/2019      JOHN        DOE  01/15/2000           0
1  01/15/2020      JANE        ROE  01/15/2010  1111111111
2  01/15/2021      BABY        DOE  01/15/2020  2222222222
```

**Recommendation is to fix the broken input file instead.**

Comment: I only had to modify the file property to `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')`, and it worked perfect!

Comment: Do you know why `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',\0', engine='python')` was not working?

Comment: A null byte is not normal in a text file so it isn’t surprising that it doesn’t work. That’s why I made a pre-filter.

Answer (score 1):

After successful import:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Exam date": ['"01/15/2019"', '"01/15/2020"', '"01/15/2021"'],
        '"Last name"': ['"JOHN"', '"JANE"', '"BABY"'],
        '"First name"': ['"DOE"', '"ROE"', '"DOE"'],
        '"DOB"': ['"01/15/2000"', '"01/15/2010"', '"01/15/2020"'],
        '"MRN"': ['"0"', '"1111111111"', '"2222222222"'],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
      Exam date "Last name" "First name"         "DOB"         "MRN"
0  "01/15/2019"      "JOHN"        "DOE"  "01/15/2000"           "0"
1  "01/15/2020"      "JANE"        "ROE"  "01/15/2010"  "1111111111"
2  "01/15/2021"      "BABY"        "DOE"  "01/15/2020"  "2222222222"
```

Here is one way to get rid of double quotes:

```py
df = df.replace("\"", "", regex=True)
df.columns = [col.strip("\"") for col in df.columns]

print(df)
# Output
    Exam date Last name First name         DOB         MRN
0  01/15/2019      JOHN        DOE  01/15/2000           0
1  01/15/2020      JANE        ROE  01/15/2010  1111111111
2  01/15/2021      BABY        DOE  01/15/2020  2222222222
```

Comment: It is possible to get rid of double quotes by using `DataFrame.replace()` and then renaming the columns, but, for example, all dtypes will remain as object and the DataFrame needs additional processing. I prefer fixing the broken input instead.